# Search a table with a lot of columns and then group the result with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website and I'm using Entity Framework code first to access its database. I have  a `Restaurants` table and I want to let users search these with a lot of parameters. Here's what I have so far:

```
public void FilterModel(ref IQueryable<Restaurant> model)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RestaurantName))
    {
        model = model.Where(r => r.Name.ToUpper().Contains(RestaurantName));
    }

    if (Recommended)
    {
        model = model.Where(r => r.SearchSponsor);
    }

    //...
}
```

Basically I look for each property and add another `Where` to the chain if it's not empty.

After that, I want to group the result based on some criteria. I'm doing this right now:

```
private static IQueryable<Restaurant> GroupResults(IQueryable<Restaurant> model)
{
    var groups = model.GroupBy(r => r.Active);
    var list = new List<IGrouping<bool, Restaurant>>();
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        list.Add(group);
    }

    if (list.Count < 1)
    {
        SortModel(ref model);
        return model;
    }

    IQueryable<Restaurant> joined, actives, inactives;
    if (list[0].FirstOrDefault().Active)
    {
        actives = list[0].AsQueryable();
        inactives = list.Count == 2 ? list[1].AsQueryable() : null;
    }
    else
    {
        actives = list.Count == 2 ? list[1].AsQueryable() : null;
        inactives = list[0].AsQueryable();
    }

    if (actives != null)
    {
        //....
    }

    if (inactives != null)
    {
        SortModel(ref inactives);
    }

    if (actives == null || inactives == null)
    {
        return actives ?? inactives;
    }

    joined = actives.Union(inactives).AsQueryable();

    return joined;
}
```

This works but it's got a lot of complications which I rather not talk about for the sake of keeping this question small.

I was wondering if this is the right and efficient way to do it. It seems kind of "dirty"! Lots of `if`s and `Where`s. Stored procedures, inverted indices, etc. This is my first "big" project and I want to learn from your experience to do this the "right" way.

Comment: Have a read on chain of responsibility pattern.  You will be able to structure your code better.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the GroupResults Method I get a little confused about what you are doing. It seems the intention is to receive an arbitrary list of restuarants and return an ordered list of restaurants ordered by Active and some other criteria.
If thats true you may just do something like this and your job's done:

```
model.OrderBy(x => x.Active).ThenBy(x => Name);
```

If SortModel is somehow more sophisticated you may either add a comparer to the statement or stick with your current solution but change it to this:

```
if (model == null || !model.Any())
{
    return model;
}
var active = model.Where(x=>x.Active);
var inactives = model.Where(x=>!x.Active);
// if (inactives == null) //not needed as where always return at least an empty list. Mabye check for inactive.Any()
SortModel(ref inactives); //You may also remove the ref as it's an reference anyway
joined = actives.Union(inactives).AsQueryable();
return joined;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Some very good points here. I'm not sure why I didn't go for the `OrderBy` but I think there was a problem with it at the time. I'll try to make this work. But the main part of my question is about searching rather than grouping. What do you think of my current method? Does it seem right?

Comment: @ Alireza Noori: I do it the same way as I find it's easy to understand and easy to maintain. I can't tell if it's the best or worst solution - I just never had problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the way you are handling your searching, I think it is simple, easy to read and understand, and it works. New team members will be able to look at that code and know immediately what it is doing and how it works. I think that is a pretty good indication that your approach is sound.